# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

Am struck with the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must 
call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

I want to create relative layout when click on the send button.

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);                                        
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
//layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 25, 0);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
TextView tv= new TextView(ChatWithFriend.this);
tv.setId(layId);
tv.setText("data");
tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
rl.addView(tv);
setContentView(rl, layoutParams);
```

Any thing  wrong on my code ?

Comment: you need to have setContentView(R.layout.mylayout) first and then you can findviewbyid of relative layout RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLayout); you can add the views to your root layout ie relative layout

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);
```

with:

```
RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
```

Your existing code uses an existing RelativeLayout, while this one makes a new one. If you want to use the existing one, you'll have to call `removeAllViews()` first to empty it.

Comment: i want to add the new layout to the parent layout

Answer (score 0):

Your root layout is relative layout. add the textview to the relative layout. You need to set the content of the layout to your activity first and then initialize relative layout. Then you can add your views to the relative layout.

Note: you can findViewById of the current view hierarchy set to the activity. So you need to set the layout to the activity first and then initialize your relative layout

Try the below

```
setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentView);                                        
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
//layoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 25, 0);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
TextView tv= new TextView(ChatWithFriend.this);
tv.setId(layId));
tv.setText("data");
tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
rl.addView(tv,layoutParams);
```

Or you can create a relativelayout as suggested by Raghav Sood and the views to the same.

Comment: Hey thanx @Raghunanda..But when i create its overlapping the old one ..any idea ?

Comment: what old one. can you show us the old one also? the xml code and the activity code

Answer (score 0):

Try following Code

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_xml);
RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parentLayout);                                        
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
TextView tv= new TextView(ChatWithFriend.this);
tv.setId(layId);
tv.setText("data");
tv.setLayoutParams(lp);
rl.addView(tv,lp);
```